# Interface 8 servo-motors with Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 (without additional micro-controller)

Tags: raspberry-pi, servo

I am using a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 as my primary processor on a control machine.

I have to interface 8 servo-motors with possible RPM feedback.

I do not wish to use an additional micro-controller for controlling the servo-motors. The micro-controller can be source of additional bugs will cause maintenance headache. There is also a problem that this board will go in a noisy environment and communication between the micro-controller and the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 could cause an issue.

I am aware that there are 2 PWM signals on the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4, but they won't suffuse my application.

Peripherals I am using in Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4:

1. I2C for external sensors
2. SPI for external sensors
3. CSI for camera
4. USB for external module

Is there any IC that I can use to control servo-motors with possible RPM feedback communicating with the processor on I2C/SPI/USB that will help me achieve the same end?

Even though I am using USB for an external module, I can add a USB hub IC on my mother-board.

I am okay having to write additional code for the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 to control the IC, but I wish to avoid writing code for the IC itself (like in the case of micro-controller.)

Comment: Are you speaking about continous rotation servos (speed controled) or classical ones (position controled, moving only 180° or 270° most of the time)? And what kind of RPM feedback do you want/need? Analog feedback (I know it exists for position, using the raw voltage of the potentiometer)? Encoder feedback (on higher end servos)? Some communication protocol (as on dynamixel servos). I think it would be best if you could give a ling to the datasheet(s) of the motor(s) you whish to use

Comment: `I do not wish to use an additional micro-controller` and `Is there any IC?` are pretty much mutually exclusive

Comment: Check out the Adafruit PWM/Servo Driver it appears to be the solution for your project.

Comment: @Sandro, I am talking about speed controlled continuous rotation servos. I just need RPM feedback once the load (impeller, propeller and chopper) is connected and get the error between actual PM and Reference RPM. For feedback I was thinking along the line of Encoder feedback. As for servo motor we are still in process of finalizing one.

Comment: @jsotola I am looking for an ASIC that needs itself does not needs to be programmed like micro-controller. I am looking for ASIC that only needs to be controlled  via Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4. If I use micro-controller I have to write two programs one for micro-controller itself and other for Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 which will issue commands to micro-controller.

Comment: That starts to be very specific!
Continuous rotation servo are already not that common. But I've never seen one so far using encoder for internal control AND outputting the encoder signals. So the existance of specific IC handling one such motor is already not certain. Let alone one handling 8 such motors. There might be some PCBs including an already programmed PCB able to do as you ask, but even that I'm not sure (you can for sure have it designed for you, but that will be expensive). You might have better luck if you go for DC motors+encoder (but you have to do the speed control yourself)

Comment: For the solution with DC motor + encoder : if you are rich, you can use roboclaw controlers (https://www.pololu.com/category/124/roboclaw-motor-controllers): you can connect up to 8 boards (controling 2 motors each) on a single serial port. Then you can use those motors in nearly any possible way (open loop, position control, speed control, with or without acceleration limitation, curent limitation ...). And you can get all feedback you want (speed, position, current, ...). They work great, but are a bit expensive (100$+). You might be able to find something similar cheaper.

Comment: Or, if you haven't choosen your servos yet, maybe just buy smart servos (dynamixel, Feetech, ...) : they are quite expensive, but include all the "fancy" stuff, so you don't need to find a fancy board to control them

Comment: @Sandro Thanks for the suggestion. Motor controller you suggested are quite expensive and will make the project economically infeasible. If we change the specification to classical ones (position controlled) are their any economical options. It looks like I have to add and program a micro-controller. I am thinking about XMC4000 series micro-controller which will communicate with raspberry pi compute module 4 over USB.

Comment: For the roboclaw controlers, we used them because we needed huge power (250W nominal per motor, about 1kW peak). For smaller motors, there should be some cheaper alternatives (I just don't know them).

But if you accept to go without feedback, then you can get away very cheap, for example using the 16 servo PBC from adafruit (15$ : https://www.adafruit.com/product/815), controntroled by I2C. It works with continous rotation servos as well as with position controled ones. But it don't has feedback